Ternary inferences in bussproofs or another prooftree package?
I'm wondering if you can do ternary inferences in bussproofs? If not, are there any other proof tree packages where you can do ternary inferences? It might be that I have to start drawing proof trees in Tikz, but I'd prefer not to.

Welcome! Not sure what you mean by a ternary inference. I would have thought you meant an inference from three premises, but \TrinaryInfC does that out-of-the-box. Could you clarify what you're not finding? Maybe https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/latex/BussGuide2.pdf helps.

Thank you very much! And yes, I mean inference rules with three premises and one conclusion. Apologies that that was not clear.  I guess I didn't look hard enough before asking here. Thanks again.

Ternary inferences are supported out-of-the-box. This example is from Peter Smith's introduction to bussproofs:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{A}
  \AxiomC{B}
  \AxiomC{C}
  \TrinaryInfC{D}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}


